# R does NOT recognize a parameter when writing a function

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to write my own function that will generate a few graphs by determining a variable. But for some reason, R isn't too happy with the following code.

```
explore = function(var, title) {
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  tr = rpart(y ~ {{var}}, data = df)
  plot(tr, margin = .1, uniform = TRUE, main = title)
  text(tr, fancy = TRUE, use.n = TRUE)
  stripchart({{var}} ~ y, main = title, data = df, method = "stack")
  boxplot({{var}} ~ y, data = df)
}
```

The output states that the "var" cannot be found from the df.
Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix base R with `tidyverse`, `{{}}` is from `tidyverse`. You can use `reformulate` to create formula object and use it.

```
explore = function(var, title) {
  formula1 <- reformulate(var, 'y')
  formula2 <- reformulate('y', var)
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  tr = rpart(formula1, data = df)
  plot(tr, margin = .1, uniform = TRUE, main = title)
  text(tr, fancy = TRUE, use.n = TRUE)
  stripchart(formula2, main = title, data = df, method = "stack")
  boxplot(formula2, data = df)
}
```